# How should I use noConflict()?

Tags: jquery

I have multipe jquery script in my page.
there are two jquery version ( 1.8 and 1.10 ) in page and multipe script like bellow :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
    var jv8 = jQuery.noConflict();
    jv8(function () {
      jv8('#discounted').attr("disabled", true);
    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var jv10 = jQuery.noConflict();
    jv10(function () {
      jv10('#discounted').attr("disabled", true);
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var jv10 = jQuery.noConflict();
    jv10(function () {
      jv10('#discounted').attr("disabled", true);
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var jv10 = jQuery.noConflict();
    jv10(function () {
      jv10('#discounted').attr("disabled", true);
    });
</script>
```

first script is using jquery version 1.8, and three scripts are using jquery version 1.10.2

but this is not working. how can I fix this? how should I use noConflict?

Comment: in `my codes` how are you referring to jQuery... also are you using any jQuery plugin if so how are they included

Comment: @ArunPJohny I updated it for you.

Comment: that should work.. even though there is no need to include the same library multiple times

Comment: @ArunPJohny : but it is not working ..

Comment: @Persian Can you be more specific about "not working"? What goes wrong? Do you see any JS errors in the console? etc

Comment: @GregL :  I cant see any error in console, I mean when page is loading, for example forth script is working bot 2 and 3 are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the script tag, you need to close it explicitly, else it will skip all the scripts till it encounters the next `</script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
  var jv8 = jQuery.noConflict();
  jv8(function ($) {
    $('#discounted').prop("disabled", true);
  });
</script>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OS3TOzUV7Lnllq5SMeqa?p=preview)

Comment: @Persian. see the attached demo.. that is working... so can you recreate the problem in the demo by editing it

Comment: should i put $ after functions?

Comment: @Persian. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Persian. not really... the dom ready handler receives the jQuery object as its param.. so I just used that to refer to jQuery in the ready handler instead of using the versioned variables.... for me that is more clean

Comment: @Persian. yes you can... copy and then save

Comment: @ArunPJohny : can you see that now ?

Comment: @Persian. you need to share the saved link... edit your question with the complete file content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74161/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-persian).